# How To make VS 2010 create x64 projects as default?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a full x64 solution and each time I create a project it is by default an x86 project and I have to witch it manually to x64. Is there a way to have this by default ?

Answer (score 3):

In C# .NET project and solution the default target platform should be "any CPU" and not x86, this means that the compiled IL is capable to run on a classic x86 and x64 system without any changes and in native mode ...

**Edit**

Sorry i just noticed that the behaviour is changed in visual studio 2010, take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/8/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx) for further information on why this choice ...

> So how is Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 changing? We are not
>   changing anything here in the CLR or compilers - they continue to
>   support both modes.  However, after discussing these issues, VS
>   project system team has agreed to make EXE projects default to the x86
>   platform in VS 2010.

Comment: Microsoft decision ... Sorry :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply modify the project template.  For example, the project template for a WPF application is stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Windows\1033\WPFApplication.zip

Open the .csproj file in that .zip file with a text editor and modify the `<Platform>` element from x86 to AnyCPU.  Make a backup copy first.